# Sorting lists inside nested lists

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a nested list:
`{{9, 8, 7}, {8, 7, 6}, {7, 6, 5}, {6, 5, 4}, {5, 4, 3}, {4, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}`

I need to sort the lists within the list to create:

`{{7, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, (1, 2, 3}}`

How do I do this?

Comment: I couldnt get what the question actually means. Could you explain the problem you are facing

Answer (score 11):

You want the [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) function, which applies a function to each element of a list.

That is, `Map[f, {1, 2, 3}]` gives `{f[1], f[2], f[3]}`.

In this case, you can use `Map[Sort, list]`. `Map` also has an infix operator, `/@`:

```
In[1]:= Map[Sort, {{9, 8, 7}, {8, 7, 6}, {7, 6, 5}, {6, 5, 4}, 
  {5, 4, 3}, {4, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}]

Out[1]= {{7, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6},
  {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}}

In[2]:= Sort /@ {{9, 8, 7}, {8, 7, 6}, {7, 6, 5}, {6, 5, 4}, 
  {5, 4, 3}, {4, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}

Out[2]= {{7, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6}, 
  {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to be aware that Ordering will also work

```
lst = {{9, 8, 7}, {8, 7, 6}, {7, 6, 5}, {6, 5, 4}, {5, 4, 3}, {4, 3, 
    2}, {3, 2, 1}};
Map[#[[Ordering[#]]] &, lst]
```

But for this type of example the approach is slower than Map/Sort

```
lst2 = RandomInteger[100, {10^5, 3}];
Map[Sort, lst2]; // Timing
Map[#[[Ordering[#]]] &, lst2]; // Timing
```

{0.175955, Null}

{1.02087, Null}

Ordering can be useful for sorting by position

```
lst3 = {{a1, 4, c1}, {a2, 3, c2}, {b3, 1, d3}, {e4, 2, f4}};
lst3[[Ordering[lst3[[All, -2]]]]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it, Map is what I had in mind.  Thank you so much.