# Is there a way to sort nested lists in Python 3+?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I am working with nested lists, and I am wondering how to alphabetize all lists while keeping them contained in their respective lists.

For example, if I had a nested lists that contained brand names:

```
lst = [['Canada Goose', 'Mackage', 'PJ'], ['GAP', 'Fendi', 'Nike'], ['Gucci', 'Adidas']]
```

And its output:

```
sorted_lst = [['Canada Goose', 'Mackage', 'PJ'], ['Fendi', 'GAP', 'Nike'], ['Adidas', 'Gucci']]
```

I know that in regular lists you can use the .sort() method however here that doesn't seem to be the case.
I also read [Sorting lists inside nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222472/sorting-lists-inside-nested-lists) and I don't seem to understand

Comment: `sorted_lst = [sorted(x) for x in lst]`?

Comment: You were probably confused because the question you were reading was not about Python.

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to use the `sort()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @SyntaxVoid

`sorted_lst = [sorted(x) for x in lst]`

Should do what you are asking.

To be clear what is going on here, is your are generating a new list of sorted lists using a generator.

[] this as you know is a list

and approximitley what is done above is similar to writing

```
    sorted_lst = []
    for x in lst:
        sorted_lst.append(sorted(x))
```

You should read https://realpython.com/python-sort/ for more help and to understand how sort and sorted work.

In addition to better understand SyntaxVoid's answer I would suggest you google Python Generator, as my explination is an apprimate example and doesn't explain the underlying deifference between my explination and the code, namely that one generates a d generator the other a list.

Answer (score 3):

AppHandwerker's solution creates a new data structure to hold the result, leaving the original `lst` unchanged. If that's a requirement, then that solution is best. It's also generally a good idea to avoid mutation, since it can lead to subtle bugs caused by [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)).

In case you don't need to keep the original data in its unsorted order, here's an [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) solution as an alternative: the advantage of sorting in-place is that it doesn't require additional memory to be allocated for the new lists holding the sorted results.

```py
for x in lst:
    x.sort()
```